# Security vulnerability domains from user input, other than SQL statements?

Tags: php, security

What type of user-submitted data needs to be sanitized -- for security reasons -- other than data that ends up in SQL statements?

For example, I know ("know") that

```
if ( isset($_POST['someVar']) && ("a_value" == $_POST['someVar']) ) {
   print "A";
} else {
   print "B";
}
```

won't give me trouble; I'm pretty sure

```
print "<table><tr><td>" . $_POST['someVar'] . '</td></tr></table>';
```

won't either.

In what domains do I need to sanitize user input (other than SQL statements), and why?

Comment: Most of time, sanitation isn't about security, but rather about correctly expressing something in a given context.  For example, you wouldn't consider writing *$var = "He said \"Hello.\""; as secure.  It's just required.  Along the same lines, SQL queries must have certain strings escaped as to be processed correctly.  Security is a byproduct since someone can abuse the lack of escaping to do harm. (This is not to say that security is not a major concern of course.)

Comment: Wasn't mine so I can't say for sure, but probably because questions just like this one are asked about every 15 minutes.

Comment: @Corbin: are they? I searched on here for a long time for questions like this before I posted.

Comment: I've noticed that they're quite hard to search for because I look for them to link to when I see questions like this one.  Of course every question is a little different, and yours is actually the first in a while that I've seen that is asking for a list of attack methods rather than one specific thing.  In my opinion though, this question is way too broad as the potential answer is infinite.  Anything that processes user data must have special care taken.  Listing all of those possibilities is not really in the spirit of a SO question.

Comment: Also, there's the factor of research effort.  As far as we can tell from your post, you did no research of your own and came straight to stackoverflow.  There are thousands of articles on the internet about PHP security, and surely you could have found a few good ones.  Maybe I'm just biased because I hate vague questions like these with a tiny example and then some huge question.

Comment: I would _guess_ the -1 came from the user who, erm, you downvoted when they were trying to help you `:-(`

Comment: @halfer: I don't usually downvote people, but their answer was not related to my question at all. Hope it doesn't make me look bad!

Comment: Their answer was related to SQL injection. They may have misread the question - you wanted to know about things other than SQL injection - but I don't think I'd downvote anyone _on my own question_ if I felt they were trying to be helpful. Still, we live and learn!

Comment: Well.. for one: your second example (that you were pretty sure wouldn't give you any trouble) allows an attacker to install a keylogger to a victim's browser. And all the other things that can be achieved through cross-site scripting. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS) Not handling user input correctly leads to almost all security vulnerabilities, in theory,  I would start with the OWASP Top Ten https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_Ten

Comment: @Cheekysoft: thank you, that's very helpful! You can put that as an answer to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Protect also where the user:

- enters HTML (user can inject malicious JavaScript, or accidentally leave tags unclosed - often it is better to use Markdown or similar)
- enters XML (user can grab your private files from the server using entity hacks)
- enters executable code such as PHP (user can run arbitrary code on your server)
- uploads files (files processed by a particular application on your server may permit buffer overflow hacks)

Comment: +1. Just to be clear, these are *domains* where I should be careful: for example, when I *want* the user to enter XML? In other words, I don't need to protect against XML vulnerabilities unless I'm asking for XML.

Comment: That's the case for XML, yes. But HTML is a tricky one - if you have an input field and someone enters their name as `halfer<img width="1" height="1" src="http://steal-cookie.bad.server.com" />` and you render it for all visitors without escaping, then you've not asked for HTML, but you still need to be aware of that vulnerability.

Comment: Actually, I should clarify the XML point; if user input that isn't XML will be used inside an XML block (or XPath query) and processed with SimpleXML or XMLReader (etc) then you should be doing some filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You protect against whatever your target environment is. If you're building a DB query, you use SQL injection protection. if the user data is going into an email, you use html & mime injection protect. html target, html injection protection.

There's no one "right" answer for this, except "use whatever your target environment's protection system is".

Comment: What is an example of a risky html target? If the user is just viewing the information they've submitted, there's no risk?

Comment: What if they wrote x<a?  Suddenly that's an HTML tag and it's not going to render correctly.

Comment: As far as security, though, that would not cause vulnerabilities. Are there cases where security could be at risk?

Comment: Well if you want to focus completely on security and not user experience...  What's he most secure application possible?  A non-existent one.  (But that would not cause a security situation as long as it was only the user seeing his own HTML.)

Comment: "As far as security, though, that would not cause vulnerabilities" - no, malformed HTML can permit a malicious user to steal the cookies of other site users. See my comment attached to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should just stop using the ancient `mysql_*` functions, and learn how to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) with either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). That would *by default* give you protection against SQL injections.

The `mysql_*` API functions for accessing MYSQL are more then 10 years ol. No longer supported by the developers an process for [deprecating](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) them has already started.

What other forms of attacks you might be vulnerable to is impossible to tell, because there is no code to look at. There are multitudes of attack vectors, which depend on what you actually use for your website.

Comment: He never even explicitly mentioned the mysql_* functions.  He may know about and be using prepared statements and just mentioned that data must be escaped in queries for completeness.  (For what it's worth though, the -1 isn't mine.)

Comment: The -1 may be from the OP; he/she just downvoted another respondent, who deleted their answer in response. I thought _that_ downvote wasn't wholly justified, fwiw.

Comment: @Corbin , thats what users history is for

Comment: -1, sorry - my question was about problems *other* than SQL injection. I don't usually downvote posts, btw.

Comment: Anything of his tagged MySQL is from a month ago, so he could have changed his coding since then (though I didn't look through things without the mysql tag).  Either way, I believe your answer does not directly address his question, but I definitely do not think it's -1 worthy as it is a very valid suggestion if he's not already using PDO.

Comment: @amindfv , problem is that there isn't any other problem to even guess at. Aside from the obvious XSS in the `<table>`. Too little code , and nothing about setup itself.

Comment: Wait, when did I not use PDO? I love PDO :)

Comment: @tereško: My question was not about the code I posted but what domains are vulnerable. What is the XSS concern with the table?

Comment: @amindfv a website could trick a user's browser into submitting a form to that page.  Then, through some JavaScript submitted as the content, the malicious user could acquire cookies or other information tied to your domain.

Comment: @amindfv .. well the list of **possible** thing is here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Web_security_exploits , And that does not take in account what other software is used in the project. Nor is it possible to dismiss any of the things in that list , because you just make a blank statement "give me all pssible vulnerabilities" ...